# Not able to spread an object with babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread added for vue cli 3 setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli, spread-syntax

This is partial code I am trying to get it working

```
const myarr = [
        {a: 'haha',},
        {b: 'yoyo',}
      ];
      const myobj = {
        a: 'some',
        b: 'kind',
      };
      console.log(myarr);
      play(...myobj);
      console.log(props);
```

So it will not have issue spreading array but when I pass spreading an object I will receive error of

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

I added `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` plugin with config, yet, same error.

What is going on here?

Here is my repo to reproduce: https://github.com/adamchenwei/vue-hoc-playground
check file `/src/components/decorator/withCustomComponent.js`
Code:

```
export default function withCustomComponent(InnerComponent) {
  return {
    mounted() {
      console.log('withCustomComponent is mounted');
    },
    render() {
      const myarr = [
        {a: 'haha',},
        {b: 'yoyo',}
      ];
      const myobj = {
        a: 'some',
        b: 'kind',
      };
      console.log(myarr);
      play(myobj);
      console.log(props);
      return <InnerComponent
        class="myinner"
        data-event="load"
        />;
    }
  }
}

export const WithCustom = {
  name: 'WithCustom',
  render() {
    const Slott = this.$slots.default[0];
    // return  <Slott />;
    return this.$slots.default[0];
    // return <h1>slott</h1>;
  }
};

function play({a,b}) {
  console.log('play')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  console.log(`${a} ${b}`);
}

function fakeCall(params, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/6078720?s=200&v=4')
  }, 1000);
}
```

Doc about spread operator for object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't use spread operator to pass an object to a function as arguments; One of the reasons behind this is that Javascript function doesn't have native support of named parameters, which makes it impossible to match the parameters by name; One workaround could be to use destructuring syntax in your `play` function as follows:

```
function play({ a, b }) {
  console.log('play')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  console.log(`${a} ${b}`);
}
```

And then you can call it with: `play(myobj)`.

Comment: thanks for answering, and I think I must missed something from your answer, because the doc indicate I should be able to spread the object in new config https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals if there is anything I may misunderstood what you saying?

Comment: Yes spread operator for object exists but it's only for spreading properties. From the docs: ***The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals.*** i.e. creating new object from existing objects, and this is different from passing object values to a function as parameters.

Comment: ahhhh I got you now. so instead of as `(a,b)` , I should be doing `({a,b})` that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: so I suppose that {...props} I did, shouldn't even work at all... cool!

Comment: @Psidom: I don't have the necessary domain knowledge to determine the folloing: in your view, is it necessary to see `withCustomComponent.js` in order to understand this question? I am trying to work out if it contains a [mcve].

Comment: @halfer I did look at the `withCustomComponent.js` to see how the `play` function is defined. It would be great if OP could include the function definition in the question to make it more complete though.